# get translated field doesnt find field

Tags: 8

I have an entity which contains a field, it has content in that field , yet when I try to programmatically set something in that field, I get

```
InvalidArgumentException: Field field_myfield  is unknown. in                                          [error]
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 509 of
C:\drupaldevsites\drupal-wcms-migration\docroot\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase.php).
```

I have run updatedb but still cannot avoid this error  .  It makes no sense since the field is there and can be edited via the UI.

I have enabled it here had to enable that field to be translated on this page /admin/config/regional/content-language  .  but still getting error.

I ran array_keys($entity->getFieldDefinitions()) and the field IS defined,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out I had a space after the field name in my set command!

```
$media->set('field_my_field_name ',array('value'=> $title));
```

instead of

```
$media->set('field_my_field_name',array('value'=> $title));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you look in the code of ContentEntityBase::getTranslatedField() in line 509

```
  $definition = $this->getFieldDefinition($name);
  if (!$definition) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Field $name is unknown.");
```

you see that this is not related to translation. The error is what it says, that the field is not defined in the entity.

You can run `array_keys($entity->getFieldDefinitions())`, before you try to store data in the entity, to check if the field is defined.

`update.php` does not update entity definitions. This happens when you install the module or run as developer `drush entity-updates` after code changes. Did you check the status page for any errors?

Comment: the field is defined because I do a GET of that field name right before the set and it show up ! also shows up on the UI.

Comment: I ran array_keys($entity->getFieldDefinitions())  and the field IS defined! this looks like a drupal bug doesnt it?

Comment: For me this seems impossible if it is the same entity. getFieldDefinition() gets the field directly from getFieldDefinitions().

Comment: I put an echo in that line and I get this :  the name is field_pup_short_desc  and lang code is x-default and it has no definition  .      How can I debug what $this is at that point? its a huge object

Comment: I checked , the id is the same , so it seems that at some point the definition has gone away, how can that be happening?

Comment: It seems that during the Set command it is taking away the definition.  how can i debug that ?

Comment: found out it was an extra space see my answer above